# Conflicting declaration for 2d array in c++?

Tags: arrays, c++11, dynamic

I came across a problem where i need to declare a 2D array dynamically.
The number of rows were known(i.e 2) while the number of columns are to taken as input.

I used this technique :

```
cin>>size;
int **outer = new int*[2];
int outer[0] = new int[size];
int outer [1] = new int[size];
```

But this gave an error : **conflicting declaration 'int outer [0]'**

Than i fixed the problem by changing my code to :

```
cin>>size;       // size of the column
int **outer = new int*[2];
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
       outer[i] = new int[size];
```

So, i want to know why can't i declare 2D array like as that of 1st , bcz i am declaring it after i have declared and defined the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
int outer[0] = ...;
```

you define a completely *new* variable named `outer`, as an array of zero elements.

Plain assignment seems to be what you want:

```
outer[0] = new int[size];
outer[1] = new int[size];
```

---

And I really recommend you don't use your own manual memory and pointer handling. First fix would be to realize that `outer` doesn't need to be a pointer but an array, as in

```
int* outer[2] = {
    new int[size],
    new int[size]
};
```

Then eliminating pointers altogether using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) you could do it as

```
std::vector<int> outer[2] = {
    std::vector<int>(size),
    std::vector<int>(size)
};
```

You should also consider replacing the C-style array with [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, 2> outer = {
    std::vector<int>(size),
    std::vector<int>(size)
};
```